# cocos2d - Creating CCSprite in UIKit Application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have a normal UIKit Application but I want to use cocos2d for a little job. I want to use the function glReadPixels, for that I need a cocos2d image -> CCSprite.

I am working for 2 days now on this problem, because I am getting this error:

> 2012-08-08 16:58:50.673 iBlaulicht 2[11801:16a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1f88022 0x1b9bcd6 0x1f30a48 0x1f309b9 0x16050c7 0x62687 0x62589 0x62317 0x86979 0x47c5c 0x2d63 0xdc5a1e 0x222d 0xcfc386 0xcfd274 0xd0c183 0xd0cc38 0xd00634 0x338cef5 0x1f5c195 0x1ec0ff2 0x1ebf8da 0x1ebed84 0x1ebec9b 0xcfcc65 0xcfe626 0x20cb 0x2065)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

this is my code:

```
    - (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)drawnImage{

    if (self == [super init]) {



        CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:drawnImage resolutionType:kCCResolutionRetinaDisplay] autorelease];
        CCSprite *imageSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];


        imageSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, 0 );
        [self addChild:imageSprite];



    }


    return self;
}


- (NSArray *)determinePixels{


    for (int y_direction = 0; currentImage.size.height > y_direction; y_direction += 20) {


        for (int x_direction = 0; currentImage.size.width > x_direction; x_direction += 20) {

            Byte pixelColor[4];
            glReadPixels(x_direction, y_direction, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelColor[0]);

            // Just to test
            NSLog(@"0");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help...Thanks.
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Look at Ray Wenderlich's post on this topic;

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit

Comment: @ChristianPappenberger any luck?

Comment: not really...can you pls provide some sample code. I really just want only a Image in cocos2d context. I wiuld appreciate your help ;)

Comment: What version of Coco2D are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15087/discussion-between-jonathanlking-and-christian-pappenberger)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself !

I added a EAGLView and used a CCDirector to set it as OpenGl View.

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)drawnImage{

    if (self == [super init]) {

        EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];


        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director setOpenGLView:glview];

        CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:drawnImage resolutionType:kCCResolutionRetinaDisplay];
        imageSprite = [KKPixelMaskSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];


        imageSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, 0 );
        [self addChild:imageSprite];



    }


    return self;
}
```